# java Spring @EnableResourceServer and @EnableWebSecurity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have **RESTful** spring resource server with `@EnableResourceServer` and extending `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`

In [documentations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableResourceServer.html) says:

> ...In order to use this filter you must @EnableWebSecurity somewhere in your application, either in the same place as you use this annotation, or somewhere else.

But when I get to the `public @interface EnableResourceServer` I see `ResourceServerConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

**Question:**
So what do I need for pure RESTful API?

1. `@EnableWebSecurity` on any `@Config`
2. Extend the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`?
3. 1 + 2
4. Neither

My config

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class HGResourceServerConfigurerAdapter extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
        .cors().disable()
        .csrf().disable()
        .formLogin().disable()
        .httpBasic().disable()
        .jee().disable()
        .logout().disable()
        .rememberMe().disable()
        .servletApi().disable()
        .x509().disable()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
        .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(Url.API_ERROR_LOGS_FRONTEND).permitAll()
        .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(Url.API_REGISTER_PATH).permitAll()
        .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(Url.API_VERIFY_EMAIL_PATH).permitAll()
        .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(Url.API_RESET_PASSWORD_PATH).permitAll()
        .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(Url.API_CONFIRM_RESET_PASSWORD_PATH).permitAll()
        .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public RemoteTokenServices tokenService() {
        RemoteTokenServices tokenService = new RemoteTokenServices();
        tokenService.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl("http://localhost:8081/oauth/check_token");
        tokenService.setClientId("client");
        tokenService.setClientSecret("secret");
        return tokenService;
    }


    //disable default user creation
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() throws Exception {
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
    }

    //password encoder
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the enable EnableWebSecurity is implicit.

I do not recommend to use WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, you will come across some troubles :
[Correctly configure spring security oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49970346/correctly-configure-spring-security-oauth2)

Comment: The @EnableResourceServer is intended to be used as Restful Api.
If you don't configure anything, your WS will be accessible only by authenticated users. In your case it could be fine. But you could have some WS that are public and accessible by everyone. In that case you need to implement ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter as you do in your question to allow access to these WS.

Comment: So option 4 is the recommended one ?

Comment: Yes, use only EnableResourceServer and ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter.

Answer (score 1):

[Spring Boot makes `@EnableWebSecurtiy` implicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44671457/what-is-the-use-of-enablewebsecurity-in-spring), but otherwise is it required.

You can prove this to yourself by taking a look at this [OAuth2 resource server example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples/oauth2/sparklr). If you remove the `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation there, you will find that the Spring Security Filter Chain is not wired.

You can still extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to separate general web application security concerns from those specific to resource server configuration. This isn't technically necessary, but can make for [a cleaner separation of concerns](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples/oauth2/sparklr/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth/examples/sparklr/config).

Comment: In the provided example, the app servers as auth and resource server in the same time. In my case, it is only resource server.